# How to Display Image in xslt

Tags: xml, xslt

I have an xml file, Nodes of that XML file contain a screenshot full path

Example  C:\usere\blablabla\name.bmp

I want to use this path in xslt to display my image, but in place to image small icon is displayed.

My code

`<img><xsl:attribute name="src"><xsl:value-of select="Screenshot_Location"/></xsl:attribute></img>`

but if i give relative path then image shows up

Comment: You need to add more details like how you are viewing the result. Without that information and the file locations it is not possible to answer your question.